# Center polygon inside a togglebutton

Tags: .net, wpf

I want a `togglebutton` with a `polygon` inside. My problem is that the `polygon` doesnt center vertically and horizontally, even after adding the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to the polygon.

My wpf code looks like this:

```
<ToggleButton Margin="12, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding ShowSelectedCountriesEnabled}" Name="ToggleButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Polygon Margin="2" Points="3,0 0,3 -3,0" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Height="10"  />
 </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

How can accomplish to center the `polygon` inside this `togglebutton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use negative coordinates you go outside of `Polygon`. Also remove `Width` and `Height` which will auto size your `Polygon` and make it easier to centre align. Second problem is you cannot horizontally align controls when you set `Orientation="Horizontal` on `StackPanel`. Is this your only control within that button? If yes remove `StackPanel` altogether and leave only `Polygon`

```
<ToggleButton ...>
   <Polygon Margin="2" Points="0,0 3,3 6,0" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aligning the `StackPanel` instead of the `Polygon`?